# Asignar una variable a un elemento de un objeto y manipularlo con la variable con Javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo el siguiente objeto:

```
auto={
      "opciones": [["auto", "verde", "alto"],["camion","azul","bajo"],["auto", "amarillo", "bajo"]]
}
```

Estoy haciendo lo siguiente:

```
var opcDos = auto[1][2]; 
console.log(opcDos); //imprime bajo
opcDos = "medio";
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

```
auto={
      "opciones": [["auto", "verde", "alto"],["camion","azul","bajo"],["auto", "amarillo", "bajo"]]
}
```

Pero espero lo siguiente:

```
auto={
      "opciones": [["auto", "verde", "alto"],["camion","azul","medio"],["auto", "amarillo", "bajo"]]
}
```

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal? ¿Cómo puedo asignar un valor a un elemento de un objeto a través de una variable?

Answer (score 1):

Tendrías que acceder al elemento del objeto y luego le asignes el nuevo valor, sería de la siguiente forma:

```
auto["opciones"][1][2] = "medio";
```

código completo:

```js
const auto = {
  "opciones": [["auto", "verde", "alto"], ["camion", "azul", "bajo"], ["auto", "amarillo", "bajo"]]
}

auto["opciones"][1][2] = "medio";

console.log(auto)
```

Si quieres hacerlo con una variable, puedes copiar el objeto, almacenar lo copiado en una variable y luego modificarlo, sería algo así:

```js
const auto = {
  "opciones": [["auto", "verde", "alto"], ["camion", "azul", "bajo"], ["auto", "amarillo", "bajo"]]
}

const opcDos = {...auto};
opcDos["opciones"][1][2] = "medio";

console.log(opcDos);
```

Comment: Se puede hacer a través de una variable ?   para no tener que poner toda la direccion del elemento??

Comment: Modifiqué mi respuesta haciéndolo con una variable, me avisa si esto es lo que necesita.

Answer (score 0):

El problema son 2 cosas.
Lo primero `auto[1][2]` no te va a devolver nada, ten en cuenta que dentro de auto esta opciones y dentro de opciones están los array, osea para obtener el valor que quieres tienes que colocar `auto.opciones[1][2]`.
El otro problema es que al guardar el valor del array en `opcDos` se trata de una variable nueva en la que solo estas guardando el valor que esta en ese momento en el array, por lo que si modificas en alguno de los 2 lados el valor, en el otro no se va a modificar.
Entonces en resumen lo que deberías hacer es:

```
auto.opciones[1][2]="medio";
```

Adicional a lo anterior, no es lo mismo quieres pero es lo mas parecido que he logrado encontrar.

Si el contenido de los array lo colocas como un objeto, y ese objeto lo pasas a una variable podras modificarlo desde afuera.

```js
auto={
      "opciones": [[{value:"auto"}, {value:"verde"}, {value:"alto"}],[{value:"camion"},{value:"azul"},{value:"bajo"}],[{value:"auto"}, {value:"amarillo"}, {value:"bajo"}]]
}

var opcDos = auto.opciones[1][2];
console.log(opcDos.value); //imprime bajo
opcDos.value="medio";

console.log(auto);
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda.

Comment: de acuerdo en lo que dices respecto a la referencia auto.opciones[1][2] pero entonces como puedo aceeder y modificar este valor a través de una variable ?

Comment: Agregue mas contenido a mi respuesta, ejecuta el código y ve si eso te ayuda con lo que quieres.